# What are some ways to improve human physiology?

Tags: science-based, biology

Imagine you have the technology to take a person and deconstruct their body and redesign it as you wish. What improvements would be possible? As an example, is there a way to restructure muscles to make them stronger? What about bones? Would it be feasible (and beneficial) to alter eyesight to see more than one spectrum? You can opt for a drastic redesign, or simply make a few tweaks. All resources needed to upkeep these new processes are readily available. The only real limitation being that it must appear to be a normal human, and it must operate through biological means/processes. I'm not talking cyborg here.

So think better, stronger, faster.

Here is a list of some ideas that I wish to incorporate:

> Increased strength/speed/endurance (and whatever changes needed to make this possible)
>   Stronger skeletal system
>   Stronger skin
>   Quicker healing
>   Increased awareness of surrounding. ("sense" living beings)
>   A way to willfully increase/decrease perception of time

How could you scientifically explain these improvements?

To help put it in context for you I will explain the events in the story. One of my characters is born with a defect that severely cripples his body. A team of doctors, along with an AI, have developed technology to help repair his condition. The way this is done is that his body is submerged in a vat of chemicals and machines and over time parts of his body are broken down and reconstructed using microscopic bio mechanical devices. During the procedure something happens to the scientists and it is up to just the AI to continue the procedure. The AI then decides to take liberties on its own and goes about "tinkering" with the patients body, resulting in the "improvements" mentioned earlier.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site! Unfortunately, asking people for their opinions is out of scope for WB SE. Tell us in what context you need this information (a character in a story you're writing needs to know what improvements to ask the crazy scientist to give him, for example) and we'll advise you, but otherwise I'm afraid that this is going to be closed. Read up on [Risk Factors](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3206/worldbuilding-scope-risk-factors?cb=1) to learn more about the site.

Comment: I updated the question, adding specific examples of what results I wanted. Did this fix the problem?

Comment: Much better. Now you're simply asking for a science-based explanation to a desired result, not just asking for opinions. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Any ideas when the topic will be reopened??

Comment: You have 3 reopen votes. You need 2 more. Patience, young padawan. (I couldn't resist)

Comment: hahaha okay thanks. I'm new and didn't know what the system was :P

Answer (score 3):

I Would remove strength inhibitors, they are there to make our muscles way weaker. Our muscles are actually strong enough to lift cars or run four times faster than Bolt but, using our muscles at their maximum power has almost certain chances to break our bones and cartilage, run out of oxygen or have an heart attack. That's why inhibitors exist.

Then I would add another heart and replace the skeleton with a sport armor  exoskeleton made of dead cells, even if the exoskeleton breaks it can be eaten and replaced in few days like how most insects do.

I would make some air inlets on the neck to get more oxygen when running.

Additionally put a symbiotic organism inside the humanoids that eats cancer cells,parasites,bacteria and dead cells.... Oh and this organism is immune to cancer itself.

And lastly I would separate the brain in two pieces, the Part that controls sensory organs will stay inside the head, the part that controls vital organs and thought will stay along the trunk.... oh and the head grows back.

Oh, almost forgot to give more power to violence inhibitors to make my humanoids more peaceful.

That's all....

Comment: Why not add in hormone regulators to improve muscle and tendon growth? Also, the amount of air you breathe isn't really a huge limiter on your blood oxygen level. Instead, I would promote the production of red blood cells. We basically have the ability to do these things through artificial hormones and blood doping.

Answer (score 0):

First would have to somehow program our immune system to recognize and Destroy cancer cells and tumors.

Second accelerate the rate our body produces new cell how to replace damaged or old cell. This would accelerate recovery from injury.

Next add some starfish DNA give us the ability to grow back limbs.

Now that we can recover from injury at accelerated rate we don't have to worry injurying ourselves on accident, we can start to remove are bodies buildt inhibitors. Allowing us to access about his full potential of speed and strength.